# How to import a function Component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function component that want to import in my app, but I'm getting:

> Invariant Violation
>   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ProjectDropContainer`.

Here is a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-voice-bdrx0

I tried importing the ProjectDropContainer like this:

```
import ProjectDropContainer from "./ProjectDropContainer";
```

or like this:

```
import {ProjectDropContainer} from "./ProjectDropContainer";
```

But still the same!

The example that I tried to do according to (and it's working) is:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/emyarod/carbon/tree/dnd-uploader-codesandbox/packages/react/examples/drag-and-drop-file-uploader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are importing an undefined `FileUploaderDropContainer` from "carbon-components-react" and using it in your `ProjectDropContainer` component. Your other import works fine. Check the doc for "carbon-components-react" to see if the `FileUploaderDropContainer` exists, its name is rightly spelled and if it is not in some subdirectory of the main module.

Comment: Pingo... Thanks a lot. my package.json was not updated and the FileUploaderDropContainer  is only with version 7.7.0

Answer (score 7):

you should export default your ProjectDropContainer component :

```
export default ProjectDropContainer
```

and then import it like this:

```
import ProjectDropContainer from "./ProjectDropContainer";
```

Comment: you sure about address function component is true?

Comment: yes, you can take a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/emyarod/carbon/tree/dnd-uploader-codesandbox/packages/react/examples/drag-and-drop-file-uploader

Comment: There is only one file in the linked sandbox